# How to redirect Page.aspx?=

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've recreated a new site using WordPress on an Apache server that used to be a .NET site, the old page URLS look like this:

```
Page.aspx?p=70
```

I need to 301 redirect all of the pages to their new pretty URLS using .htaccess

When I use

```
Redirect 301 /Page.aspx?p=70 http://example.com/foobar
```

It doesn't work, and WordPress sends it to

```
/?attachment_id=70
```

My .HTACCESS looks like this

```
Redirect 301 /Page.aspx?p=70 http://example.com/foobar

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Please share your entire .htaccess

Comment: @Bjorn I've added the .htaccess now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=70$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^Page\.aspx$ /foobar? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And remember that `%{QUERY_STRING}` is not matched using `Redirect` directive.

Comment: Yes this works! Thank you! Do you know if it would be a problem to do this for 70 pages?

Comment: No 70 is not that much for rewrite rules. I have seen more than 1000 rules like this. Also can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.